# Would a multi entry schengen visa get cancelled upon applying for family reunion visa?

Tags: schengen, family

My wife(non EU) has a 1 year schengen visa issued by the Netherlands. She has used it already twice, once to Netherlands and second time to Denmark/Germany last year. We had got married in Denmark with this visa.

I am a resident of Germany (non EU citizen) and she has already applied for family reunion visa for Germany. The family reunion visa obviously takes a couple of months to process and I was wondering if she is still eligible to reuse the schengen visa to travel to Germany, while the other visa is under process, provided she meets the criteria of a tourist (return ticket, sufficient finance, 90/180 rule).

I am pretty sure, the immigration can already see the family visa under processing and wondering if the schengen visa is somehow cancelled due to the family visa processing? Would she get denied at immigration?

Additional Info:
She has stayed around 70 days in total last year. It is already been 6 months since her last visit. Visa is still valid for 5 more months from now. I understand she can still stay another 90 days provided the visa is still valid.

Comment: Have you tried asking any of the relevant German authorities?  I suspect that her Schengen visa remains valid, but I wonder whether the pending German application means that she should not be *in Germany.*  In any event, I am unable to cite any credible or official sources.